# Dockerfile for Laravel deployment

Tags: bash, laravel, dockerfile

I'm looking for reviews about my first dockfile. I don't want to develop bad habits.

The purpose is to quickly deploy my Laravel (5.4) application. I'm going to connect it with others database containers (mognodb and mysql).

I used Ubuntu as parent image because it's my development environment but I planned to change it to debian or alpine later.

```
# Use an official Ubuntu LTS as a parent image
FROM ubuntu:16.04

MAINTAINER name <email>

#================================= Dependencies ================================

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get -qq update && \
    apt-get -qq install -y --no-install-recommends \
        apache2 \
        composer \
        curl \
        git \
        libapache2-mod-php7.0 \
        libssl-dev \
        libsslcommon2-dev \
        npm \
        php-curl \
        php-dev \
        php-mbstring \
        php-mysql \
        php-pear \
        php-xml \
        php-zip \
        php7.0 \
        phpunit \
        pkg-config \
        zip && \
    # Get repository for node 8 and install it
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash && \
    apt-get -qq install -y nodejs && \
    # Remove useless package : curl
    apt-get autoremove --purge -y curl && \
    # Clean temporary apt data
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install php dependencies
RUN pecl -q install mongodb

#================================= Php Settings ================================

# Enable Mongo driver
RUN echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini && \
    echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

#=============================== Apache Settings ===============================

# Set Apache environment variables
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/run/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2

# Create Apache directories
RUN mkdir -p $APACHE_RUN_DIR $APACHE_LOCK_DIR $APACHE_LOG_DIR

# Enable 'mod_rewrite' for rewrite URL then remove 'index.php'
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Copy Apache configuration file
COPY apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

#================================= App Download ================================

# Create App directory
RUN mkdir /var/www/app
WORKDIR /var/www/app

# Copy sources without version control
RUN git clone --branch=v2.0.1 \
    https://my_name:my_key@bitbucket.org/app/repository.git . \
    && find . -name ".git*" -type f -delete

# Add write access to storage and cache
RUN chmod -R a+w storage/ bootstrap/cache/

#========================== Download / Install Vendors =========================

# Download PHP vendors
# Clean cache
RUN composer -q install && \
    composer clear-cache

# Download CSS/JS vendors
# Compile required assets
# Clean cache and download
RUN npm -q install && \
    npm run production && \
    rm -rf node_modules && \
    npm cache clean --force

#================================= App Settings ================================

# Set .env file with relevent settings
RUN sed -i 's/APP_ENV=\S*/APP_ENV=production/' .env && \
    sed -i 's/APP_DEBUG=\S*/APP_DEBUG=false/' .env &&

#=================================== Cleanup ===================================

# Clean temporary Laravel data
RUN php artisan cache:clear && \
    php artisan view:clear && \
    php artisan config:cache

# Remove useless folders
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html

#================================ Run Container ================================

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Run Apache in the background
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/sbin/apache2" ]
CMD ["-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

After building the image size is 550 MB.
And after run the container the application work like expected.

What is right, and wrong with this dockerfile? How could I optimise it?

Answer (score 3):

I don't much about Docker, so I can't comment much on that.
I've read through the file and the steps seem to make sense.
I can comment on some details.

The comment here doesn't match what the code does,
because the `find` command will only delete files like `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes`, but the `.git` directory itself with the full history remains:

> ```
> # Copy sources without version control
> RUN git clone --branch=v2.0.1 \
>     https://my_name:my_key@bitbucket.org/app/repository.git . \
>     && find . -name ".git*" -type f -delete
> ```

If you don't need the version control history,
perhaps you can use a zip file release instead of cloning.
Or, you might want to change the `find` command to delete the `.git` directory too,
by dropping the `-type f` condition.

The `sed` commands here duplicate the variable names,
seem overcomplicated to use `\S*` instead of simply `.*`,
can be more strict to not perform the replacement in comment lines,
and can be combined into a single command:

> ```
> RUN sed -i 's/APP_ENV=\S*/APP_ENV=production/' .env && \
>     sed -i 's/APP_DEBUG=\S*/APP_DEBUG=false/' .env &&
> ```

Like this:

```
RUN sed -ie '/^APP_ENV=/s/=.*/=production/' -e '/^APP_DEBUG=/s/=.*/=false/' .env
```

Comment: It seems like the good use of sed command is : `sed -i .env -e '/^APP_ENV=/s/=.*/=production12/' -e '/^APP_DEBUG=/s/=.*/=false/'`. But I don't get why `\S*` is not good, what is the difference with your approach?

Comment: @Opsse `\S*` is fine, it just seems unnecessary. `sed -i .env` would be a bit confusing, because the `-i` flag has an optional parameter as backup file extension. `sed -i .env -e '...'` makes it look like the `.env` might be an option of `-i`, but it's not. With `sed -ie '...' .env` there won't be such misunderstanding.

Comment: I understand but `sed -ie '...' .env` do not works

Comment: @Opsse what do you mean by "it does not work"? Do you get an error?

Comment: With `sed -ie '...' -e '...' .env` I got `sed: can't read /^APP_ENV=/s/=.*/=production/: No such file or directory`. It takes the first '...' as a file with multiple `-e`.

Comment: @Opsse how about: `RUN sed -i -e '/^APP_ENV=/s/=.*/=production/' -e '/^APP_DEBUG=/s/=.*/=false/' .env`

Answer (score 0):

I would have started with `FROM 7.0-apache.` I would have also install npm **AFTER** adding the nodejs module.

I assume this is a PHP app and nodejs is just used for javascript dependency management.